# Using Cramer's Method

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

How do I use Cramer's method to solve the following system of equations ?

2x+2=10

2y=2

2-3y=6x

I've solved for y using standard simultaneous equations but this didn't help

Comment: $x=4$, $y=1$, and the last equation does not look consistent to me.

Comment: don't worry I was miss informed about the question will be taking this down

Answer (score 0):

The the system of equations be the matrix A. Note that you want the determinant of A to be non-zero. This implies that your system has a unique solution.

Cramer's Rule says that you can calculate your (x,y,z) solution by determinants.

x= det(M1)/det(A), y= det(M2)/det(A), z=det(M3)/det(A)

Now M1-M3 represent your regular matrix but only your solution (right hand side of original system) is replaced in column 1,2 and 3 respectively while the rest of the matrix the same. Once you compute these you have your answer.

Now if we look at your equations and form a matrix and find the determinate we see that det(A)=0 which means we cannot use Cramer's Rule on you system.

So to answer your question, you can't use Cramer's Rule to solve the system.